# Get child count in binary tree in Sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, binary-tree, recursive-query

I have a legacy system system based on following structure [image]

there is a userid, name, parent, and side.  Here side is tinyint (0 = left , 1 = right) which means the side on which current user is located.

Now I just wanted to have a count of children of a specific node. 
I have a recursive solution, but it halts with the increment in size of data.

```
 WITH MyCTE AS (
         SELECT  node.username, node.referenceID
         FROM Members as node        
         WHERE node.referenceID = 'humansuceess10'       
         UNION ALL     SELECT parent.username, parent.referenceID   
         FROM Members  as parent , MyCTE as x     
         WHERE x.username=  parent.referenceID   
         )      SELECT  COUNT(username)  FROM MyCTE option (maxrecursion 0) ;
```

I have tested this query on 15000 records and unfortunately it stuck and resulted in a time out error.

I'm looking for a non-recursive solution.

Comment: hopefully those aren't real username & email addresses

Comment: no that's the Dummy Data @SteveFord